# c# No overload matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue but I'm not really sure on what needs to be changed,

Here is the code:

```
private void UploadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionstring = @"{serverconnectionstring};";
            using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionstring))
            {
                using (var p = new ChoCSVReader(mainFile).WithFirstLineHeader())
                {
                    bcp.DestinationTableName = "ReceiptDemo";
                    bcp.EnableStreaming = true;
                    bcp.BatchSize = 10000;
                    bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    bcp.NotifyAfter = 100;
                    bcp.SqlRowsCopied += delegate (object sender,SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.RowsCopied.ToString("#,##0") + " rows copied.");
                    };
                    bcp.WriteToServer(p.AsDataReader());
                }

            }
        }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0123  No overload for 'UploadData_Click' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'    Rceipt  C:\Users\user\Documents\ReceiptApp\Rceipt\MainWindow.xaml   17  Active
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0136  A local or parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter       C:\Users\user\Documents\ReceiptApp\Rceipt\MainWindow.xaml.cs    84
```

Comment: You already have a `sender` and an `e` variable.  Use different names for your delegate.

Comment: Can they be named anything? @LarsTech

Comment: Yeah the param types are what are important so you can name them whatever as long as the param count matches as well as the types, I would also consider moving over to use lambdas over the very old fashioned anonymous methods
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the second error: This happens because your delegate in `bcp.SqlRowsCopied += delegate (object sender,SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)` has a arguments named `sender` and `e` which are equal to an enclosing method's arguments. Rename both arguments to something else.

The first error is probably a followup. Unless you have manually edited the method declaration, it should automatically be created when you added the event handler in the XAML editor.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work, but now I'm getting this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0123 No overload for 'UploadData_Click' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler' Rceipt C:\Users\user\Documents\ReceiptApp\Rceipt\MainWindow.xaml 17 Active @PMF

Comment: Weird, that should match. Try a rebuild. Looking at the intelisense suggestions at the place of the error might help, too.